# how do you write java statements that opens a new binary file named binout.txt and assigns a reference to the connection to binobj

Tags: java, binaryfiles

can someone please help me with this:

how do you write java statements that opens a new binary file named binout.txt and assigns a reference to the connection to binobj.

it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Kind of weird to have .txt extension for a binary file ...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FileOutputStream binobj = new FileOutputStream("binout.txt");
```

Is this homework/